# MongoDB issue with saving value returned from findByID

Tags: mongodb

I have an issue with function which update password. What I would like to have is a function which will update logged user data.

```
export const updateMe = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req) {
    res.status(400).end()
  }

  try {
    const updatedDoc = await User.findById(req.user._id, function(err, doc) {
      if (err) return next(err)

      doc.password = req.body.password

      doc.save()
    })
      .lean()
      .exec()

    res.status(200).json({ data: updatedDoc })
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    res.status(400).end()
  }
}
```

I have written middleware which will hash password before it will be saved.

```
userSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
  if (!this.isModified('password')) {
    return next()
  }

  bcrypt.hash(this.password, 8, (err, hash) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    }

    this.password = hash
    next()
  })
})
```

I do not know why error is always reciving with message "doc.save() is not a funcition"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing promise and await code, also doc.save() returns a promise so you need to await it.

( I assume you are already setting req.user._id in a middleware, and it is not null.)

So your method must be like this if async/await is used:

```
export const updateMe = async (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.body.password) {
    return res.status(400).send("Password is required");
  }

  try {
    let updatedDoc = await User.findById(req.user._id);

    updatedDoc.password = req.body.password;

    updatedDoc = await updatedDoc.save();

    res.status(200).json({ data: updatedDoc });
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    res.status(400);
  }
};
```